# How to call a link with requestparameter inside loop

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to reference an index in a URL,
for the controller shown below,
such that when the button for first item in the list is clicked,
the corresponding URL to be called is:

```
/product/detailpage/index/0 ->for the first item 
/product/detailpage/index/2 ->for the third item
and so on
```

How do I modify the code and the <form in code_1 section to satisfy these requirements?

**HTML:**

```
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="product, iter  : ${list}">
            <td th:text="*{product.id}"></td>
            <td th:text="*{product.name}"></td>
            <td style="text-align: right;">
                <form action="@{/product/detailpage/index/(idx=${iter.index})}">
                    <input type="submit" value="Details" />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

**Java:**

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/product/detailpage")
public class ProductDetailPageController
{
    /**
     * It is the developer's responsibility to provide code that handles
     * the concatenation the correct index to this AttributeName,
     * so as to get the the corresponding value from the Model data structure.
     * For example, productDetailAtIndex_0,
     *              productDetailAtIndex_1,
     *              productDetailAtIndex_n
     */
    public static final String sProductDetailPageAttrName = "productDetailAtIndex_";

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    /**
    * Solution-1
    */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/index/{idx}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to see `/product/detailpage/index/0` instead of `/product/detailpage/index/?idx=0`?  You just need to add a placeholder that matches your chosen variable name.  Like this:

```
th:action="@{/product/detailpage/index/{idx}(idx=${iter.index})}"
```

or for a url

```
th:url="@{/product/detailpage/index/{idx}(idx=${iter.index})}"
```